# The set of values for $p \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the function$f(x)=\sqrt{\log_7(\frac{2x^2+px+5}{x^2+1})}$ is defined for every real number is:

Tags: functions

There are five possible answers. I don't know how to solve this, I can define for when $2x^2+px+5$ is bigger than $0$ but don't know how to proceed

$A:(-4,4)$
$B: (-\infty,-4)$
$C: (-\infty,4)$
$D: [-4,4]$
$E: Empty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\log(y) \geq 0 \iff y \geq 1$.

Comment: Using this, I get that $p^2>16$ which represents none of the possible answers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welp, stupid mistake, thanks!